# Multiple Organizational Units (OU) ASN.1 encoding differences

Tags: x509, asn.1, ou

I have come across two different ways of encoding multiple OUs.
One is to list the multiple OUs at the same level as other identifier, such as

```
SEQUENCE {
   SET {
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER commonName (2 5 4 3)
       PrintableString 'tester'
       }
     }
   SET {
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
       UTF8String 'department1'
       }
     }
   SET {
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
       UTF8String 'org1'
       }
     }
}
```

Another is to embed the OUs as a list as follow

```
SEQUENCE {
   SET {
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER commonName (2 5 4 3)
       PrintableString 'tester'
       }
     }
   SET {
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
       PrintableString 'department1'
       }
     SEQUENCE {
       OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
       PrintableString 'org1'
       }
     }
}
```

And some tools would decode the 2nd encoding as 1 OU only, representing it as follow

```
organizationalUnitName    = department1 + organizationalUnitName    = org1
```

I am just wondering which way is the better, or more common way to encode multiple OUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first encoding (SET nests only one SEQUENCE), RDN attributes are printed/decoded in exact order as they are encoded:

```
OU=org1, OU=department1, CN=tester
```

In second example (SET nests multiple SEQUENCEs), RDN attributes inside single SET can be reordered and may result in two paths:

```
OU=org1, OU=department1, CN=tester
OU=department1, OU=org1, CN=tester
```

And these two paths are not same. This is because SET is an unordered list and application is free to order them as they need/want. Therefore, I would recommend to use first encoding, i.e. only one SEQUENCE inside SET. This guarantees that X.500 name results in same path in all conforming implementations.

p.s. I just tested this with Microsoft implementation of X.500 decoder. It doesn't re-ordrer multiple SEQUENCEs inside SET and decodes in exact order as RDNs are encoded, i.e. `OU=org1, OU=department1, CN=tester`

p.p.s. keep in mind that RDNs shall be encoded from tree root down to leaf node. Your encoding is opposite and may lead to undesired string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out in the p.p.s. So basically, there is no set rules on how to encode multiple OUs in a X.509 certificate except for the concerns that order of the OUs might not be as desired.

Comment: At least, I'm not aware of any such spec. I would stick with first option (one SEQUENCE inside SET) since it provides consistent result and is de-facto standard in Internet PKI, so is highly compatible.